How to get URL web-app from telegram bot from button?
I need to get a customized URL, one that can be run in a browser.
Such buttons are attached to massages, and look like on this screenshot (they have a label on the top right).
(https://i.sstatic.net/K0n8SuGy.png)
I tried to get the URL via KeyboardButtonSimpleWebView, but that doesn't work, also I tried to get the URL using this code, but that didn't work either:
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='TONStartBot'))
async def mi_handler(event):
    If 'Kind' in event.raw_text:
        async for message in client.iter_messages('TONStartBot', limit=1, from_user='TONStartBot'):
            await message.click(0)
        url = event.message.buttons[0][0].url
        print(url)  
        url_part = url.split('=')[1]
        print(url_part)


To extract the URL from a Telegram bot's inline keyboard button, you can use the url attribute of the InlineKeyboardButton object. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
from telethon import events

@client.on(events.CallbackQuery(chats='TONStartBot'))
async def mi_handler(event):
    if 'Kind' in event.data:
        url = event.data['button']['url']
        print(url)
        url_part = url.split('=')[1]
        print(url_part)


ChatGPT generated answer?
